# DataBound event is not available for DataList control in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, datalist

I am working on a project in ASP.Net, in which I am using `DataList` control to list
the candidate data. As we know, `DataBoud` event is available for `gridview` control, which
is raises after databound.

In `DataList` control no such event is available. Yes, `ItemDataBound` event is there
 which is arises on every Item bound.
    Let us assume, that I want the number of items are listed in datalist, after 
completing the data bound of datalist.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Indeed the `DataList` control does not expose a `DataBound` event. The latter was introduced in ASP.NET 2 (with the [BaseDataBoundControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basedataboundcontrol.databound.aspx)).

In your case you can use a different event to achieve your goal. The [PreRender](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.prerender.aspx) event looks like a good candidate.

Answer (score 0):

The number of items in the DataList will be equal to the number of records in the underlying DataSource.  Also, you can use the PreRender event for this purpose.